# How to render an After Effects composition without DRM protection

Tags: after-effects

How can you render a .wmv video file in After Effects without DRM protection, there doesn't seem to be an option when rendering.

**UPDATE**

This composition im rendering is basically a small animation i made from scratch, so i know im not rendering it with any pre-rendered files

Comment: Is it your own composition, or does it come from a DRM protected file?

Comment: What format are you using that has DRM protection on it?  This is not a typical behavior of After Effects.  Do you typically produce DRM protected media from the system?

Answer (score 1):

I've never seen this kind of behavior in After Effects.  I'm going to assume that you are using a system that is typically used for producing DRM protected media and that the default options for your Windows Media format are setup to use a DRM system.  This would be part of the configuration of the encoder itself and should be available from the encoding and format options (not the exact name, I don't have AE on my current computer to check, but it's the setting right below quality level in the render queue.)

Without knowing the exact encoder being used, I can't really give any more direct feedback than that.  If you can post the exact encoder being used and the version of AE, I can give some more specific instructions later when I am at my home desktop.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a Mac, you need to buy Flip for Mac Studio in order to be able to export wmv files.  It costs $50. The more expensive version lets you export using two-pass encoding.

http://www.telestream.net/flip4mac/

I don't you have an issue with DRM in After Effects when using this.